# Why executables aren't written in a way that the OS understand instead of machine code?

Tags: compilation, computer-science, executable, machine-code

We know that computer programs are either AOT compiled, JIT compiled or interpreted

And we also know that AOT compiled programs usually get compiled from its high level source code into machine code

Now the question is, if machine code is so hard to understand and write, why the idea of compilers wasn't to translate programs into a simpler language understood by the operating system instead of translating directly into machine code

And if such operating-system-dependent language existed, the OS should read the executables written in it and translate them into the corresponding machine code understood by the CPU

In other words, wouldn't the process of compiling into machine code have been easier if OSs had some kind of JIT compiler (VM?) that translated a specific kind of bytecode (which should exist) into machine code?

Are there any disadvantages of all this?

Comment: `if machine code is so hard to understand and write` it is mostly false assumption, anyway - main reason is performance, interpreted languages always slower in comparison to similar code compiled, jit compiler can compete with AOT, but it still takes some time at the very start to run compilation and for applications like word or photoshop - compilation can take hours, do you want to wait several hours *each* time you start app?

Comment: How would this OS-dependent byte-code and VM be an improvement over current byte-code that is OS-independent, such as with Java and C#?